# When I invalidate my timer, how do I use it again?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My code looks something like this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

timer = [NSTimer scheduledWithTimeInterval:0.015 and so on and so on ......

}

-(void)stop {

[timer invalidate];

}

-(void)start {

}
```

How do I start the timer again once it has stopped?

Comment: You can't, as is clearly stated in the documentation ( Invalidate -"Stops the receiver from ever firing again and requests its removal from its run loop"). You need to create a new one.

Comment: Please consult the documentation before wasting bandwidth. It is very clear about this.

Comment: @matt I think ive gotten enough answers from a lot of people thank you very much. Your comment is not any more or less helpful than the previous responses I have

Comment: @CyrilIvarGarcia I'm teaching you how to be both a better programmer and a better Stack Overflow citizen. Reading the documentation should be your _first_ resort. Learn to use the documentation and you learn to help _yourself_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.  Once invalidated a timer object is no longer usable and a new one should be created.

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate) `-invalidate`:

> Stops the receiver from ever firing again and requests its removal
>   from its run loop.